# How to apply a transition to a JS slider?

Tags: css

In the snippet below, I have a JS-based slider. I'm trying to add transition to the slider, and I've added `transition: all 1s ease;` to multiple elements, but nothing is transitioning as intended.

FYI - The slider is only available at 1200px+ viewport.

**How do I add a transition between slides so they ease in when navigated?**

```js
//handles slider
let toggleSlide = function () {
  document.querySelectorAll(".video-slider.active");
  this.classList.add("active");
  this.nextElementSibling(".video-slider");
  this.classList.add(".video-slider:first");
  this.at(-1);
  this.classList.add("active");
};

for (const control of document.querySelectorAll(".nav-arrows .arrow")) {
  control.addEventListener("click", function () {
    const slides = [...document.querySelectorAll(".video-slider")];
    let index = slides.findIndex((slide) => slide.classList.contains("active"));
    slides[index].classList.remove("active");
    index =
      (index + (control.id === "left-arrow" ? -1 : 1) + slides.length) %
      slides.length;
    slides[index].classList.add("active");
  });
}

// handles Wistia
var firstPlay = false;
$(".people-love-nextiva .vid-ct").on("click", function () {
  var videoId = "";

  var videoNum = $(this).find(".vid-thumb").attr("id");

  if (videoNum == "video-1") {
    videoId = "2uzup7d1l3";
  } else if (videoNum == "video-2") {
    videoId = "h16fin8bfq";
  } else if (videoNum == "video-3") {
    videoId = "i0ijlogr4q";
  }

  if (!$(this).hasClass("played")) {

    if (firstPlay == false) {
      $(this).prepend('<script src="https://fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js" async><\/script>');
      firstPlay = true;
    }

    $(this).find(".vid-thumb").remove();

    $(this).hide().prepend(
      '<script src="https://fast.wistia.com/embed/medias/' +
        videoId + 
        '.jsonp" async><\/script><div class="wistia_embed wistia_async_' +  
        
        videoId + 
        ' videoFoam=true" style="width:100%;">&nbsp;</div>'
      ).fadeIn(1250);
    // Wistia JavaScript API calls
    window._wq = window._wq || [];
    // Pauses any currently playing video and plays specific video that was clicked
    _wq.push(
      {
        id: "_all",
        onReady: function (video) {
          video.pause();
        }
      },
      {
        id: videoId,
        onReady: function (video) {
          video.play();
        }
      }
    );
    // Add class played so if statement above knows whether a vid-ct has already been clicked
    $(this).addClass("played");
  }
});
```

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.img-fluid {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.people-love-nextiva .w-css-reset[data-handle="thumbnail"],
.people-love-nextiva .w-css-reset[data-handle="bigPlayButton"] {
  display: none !important;
}

.people-love-nextiva {
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background: white;
  max-width: 1200px;
  position: relative;
}

.people-love-nextiva .container {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-left: 36px;
  padding-right: 36px;
}

.people-love-nextiva h2 {
  font-size: 2.25rem;
  line-height: 2.75rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.video-sliders {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}

.video-slider {
  display: flex;
  height: fit-content;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: #ebeff5;
  position: relative;

  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}

.video-sliders .video-slider.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: flex;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .video-slider {
    flex-direction: unset;
    flex-flow: row;
    align-items: center;
    background: linear-gradient(
      to right,
      #ebeff5 0px,
      #ebeff5 600px,
      #fff 600px,
      #fff 100%
    );
    max-width: 1200px;
  }
}
.video-slider__video {
  order: 1;
}
.video-slider__video .vid-ct {
  min-height: 185px;
  width: 85vw;
  max-width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .people-love-nextiva {
    padding-bottom: 5rem;
  }

  .video-slider__video .vid-ct {
    min-height: 388px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .video-slider__video .vid-ct {
    min-height: 432px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .video-slider__video .vid-ct {
    min-height: 432px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .people-love-nextiva {
    padding-bottom: 7rem;
  }

  .video-slider__video {
    width: 840px;
    order: 2;
  }
}
.video-slider__content {
  padding: 2rem;
  order: 1;
  height: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .video-slider__content {
    order: 1;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 600px;
  }
}
.video-slider__content h6.kicker.kicker--light {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  line-height: 0.75rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.video-slider__content h4 {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  line-height: 2.25rem;
  font-weight: 900;
}
.video-slider__content p {
  margin-top: 1.25rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}
.video-slider__content .txt-link {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.video-slider__nav {
  display: none;
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .video-slider__nav,
  .nav-arrows {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .video-slider__nav {
    max-width: 1200px;
  }

  .video-sliders .video-slider__nav {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 6.5rem;
    left: 0;
    padding: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .video-sliders .video-slider__nav svg:first-child {
    margin-right: 0.625rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="people-love-nextiva">
    <div class="container no-pad">
      <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-start">
        <h2>People love Me.</h2>
        <div class="video-sliders">
          <div class="video-slider active">
            <div class="video-slider__video">
              <div class="vid-ct">
                <div class="vid-thumb" id="video-1">
                  <img class="img-fluid vid-thumb-img lazy" src="https://via.placeholder.com/840x473.png?text=Image+One" alt="Alt Text">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="video-slider__content">
              <div class="video-slider__content-inner">
                <h6 class="kicker kicker--light">
                  Customer Story
                </h6>
                <h4>Company Name</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Iste, itaque.</p>
                <span class="txt-link arrow-link">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
                  <img alt="arrow right icon" class="learn-more-arrow" src="https://nextivaweb.imgix.net/icons/Arrow-Right-Hover-Animation.svg" loading="lazy">
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>          
          </div>
          <div class="video-slider">
            <div class="video-slider__video">
              <div class="vid-ct">
                <div class="vid-thumb" id="video-2">
                  <img class="img-fluid vid-thumb-img lazy" src="https://via.placeholder.com/840x473.png?text=Image+Two" alt="Alt Text">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="video-slider__content">
              <div class="video-slider__content-inner">
                <h6 class="kicker kicker--light">
                  Customer Story
                </h6>
                <h4>Another Company</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam est distinctio animi optio eum vero!</p>
                <span class="txt-link arrow-link">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
                  <img alt="arrow right icon" class="learn-more-arrow" src="https://nextivaweb.imgix.net/icons/Arrow-Right-Hover-Animation.svg" loading="lazy">
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>          
          </div>
          <div class="video-slider">
            <div class="video-slider__video">
              <div class="vid-ct">
                <div class="vid-thumb" id="video-3">
                  <img class="img-fluid vid-thumb-img lazy" src="https://via.placeholder.com/840x473.png?text=Image+Three" alt="Alt Text">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="video-slider__content">
              <div class="video-slider__content-inner">
                <h6 class="kicker kicker--light">
                  Customer Story
                </h6>
                <h4>Third Company</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis!</p>
                <span class="txt-link arrow-link">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
                  <img alt="arrow right icon" class="learn-more-arrow" src="https://nextivaweb.imgix.net/icons/Arrow-Right-Hover-Animation.svg" loading="lazy">
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>          
          </div>          
          <div class="video-slider__nav">
            <div class="nav-arrows">
              <svg id="left-arrow" class="arrow" fill="none" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <g stroke="#000a70" stroke-width="2.5">
                  <path d="m9 1-7 7 7 7"></path>
                  <path d="m2.5 8h13.5"></path>
                </g>
              </svg>
              <svg id="right-arrow" class="arrow" fill="none" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <g stroke="#000A70" stroke-width="2.5">
                  <path d="m1 8h13.5"></path>
                  <path d="m8 15 7-7-7-7"></path>
                </g>
              </svg>              
            </div>
          </div>                    
        </div>                       
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: we can't use display:none if we want to animate that div (unless using jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

We can't add transition property for elements using `display:none`. Perhaps here's a small work around for that.

```js
//handles slider
let toggleSlide = function () {
  document.querySelectorAll(".video-slider.active");
  this.classList.add("active");
  this.nextElementSibling(".video-slider");
  this.classList.add(".video-slider:first");
  this.at(-1);
  this.classList.add("active");
};
var clientHeight = document.getElementsByClassName('video-slider')[0].clientHeight;
document.getElementById("video-sliders").style.height = clientHeight+'px';
for (const control of document.querySelectorAll(".nav-arrows .arrow")) {
  control.addEventListener("click", function () {
    const slides = [...document.querySelectorAll(".video-slider")];
    let index = slides.findIndex((slide) => slide.classList.contains("active"));
    slides[index].classList.remove("active");
    index =
      (index + (control.id === "left-arrow" ? -1 : 1) + slides.length) %
      slides.length;
    slides[index].classList.add("active");
  });
}

// handles Wistia
var firstPlay = false;
$(".people-love-nextiva .vid-ct").on("click", function () {
  var videoId = "";

  var videoNum = $(this).find(".vid-thumb").attr("id");

  if (videoNum == "video-1") {
    videoId = "2uzup7d1l3";
  } else if (videoNum == "video-2") {
    videoId = "h16fin8bfq";
  } else if (videoNum == "video-3") {
    videoId = "i0ijlogr4q";
  }

  if (!$(this).hasClass("played")) {

    if (firstPlay == false) {
      $(this).prepend('<script src="https://fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js" async><\/script>');
      firstPlay = true;
    }

    $(this).find(".vid-thumb").remove();

    $(this).hide().prepend(
      '<script src="https://fast.wistia.com/embed/medias/' +
        videoId + 
        '.jsonp" async><\/script><div class="wistia_embed wistia_async_' +  
        
        videoId + 
        ' videoFoam=true" style="width:100%;">&nbsp;</div>'
      ).fadeIn(1250);
    // Wistia JavaScript API calls
    window._wq = window._wq || [];
    // Pauses any currently playing video and plays specific video that was clicked
    _wq.push(
      {
        id: "_all",
        onReady: function (video) {
          video.pause();
        }
      },
      {
        id: videoId,
        onReady: function (video) {
          video.play();
        }
      }
    );
    // Add class played so if statement above knows whether a vid-ct has already been clicked
    $(this).addClass("played");
  }
});
```

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.img-fluid {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.people-love-nextiva .w-css-reset[data-handle="thumbnail"],
.people-love-nextiva .w-css-reset[data-handle="bigPlayButton"] {
  display: none !important;
}

.people-love-nextiva {
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background: white;
  max-width: 1200px;
  position: relative;
}

.people-love-nextiva .container {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-left: 36px;
  padding-right: 36px;
}

.people-love-nextiva h2 {
  font-size: 2.25rem;
  line-height: 2.75rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.video-sliders {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}

.video-slider {
  display: flex;
  height: fit-content;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: #ebeff5;
  position: relative;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  transition: 1.5s ease all;
}

.video-sliders .video-slider.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: flex;
  left: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .video-slider {
    flex-direction: unset;
    flex-flow: row;
    align-items: center;
    background: linear-gradient(
      to right,
      #ebeff5 0px,
      #ebeff5 600px,
      #fff 600px,
      #fff 100%
    );
    max-width: 1200px;
  }
}
.video-slider__video {
  order: 1;
}
.video-slider__video .vid-ct {
  min-height: 185px;
  width: 85vw;
  max-width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .people-love-nextiva {
    padding-bottom: 5rem;
  }

  .video-slider__video .vid-ct {
    min-height: 388px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .video-slider__video .vid-ct {
    min-height: 432px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .video-slider__video .vid-ct {
    min-height: 432px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .people-love-nextiva {
    padding-bottom: 7rem;
  }

  .video-slider__video {
    width: 840px;
    order: 2;
  }
}
.video-slider__content {
  padding: 2rem;
  order: 1;
  height: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .video-slider__content {
    order: 1;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 600px;
  }
}
.video-slider__content h6.kicker.kicker--light {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  line-height: 0.75rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.video-slider__content h4 {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  line-height: 2.25rem;
  font-weight: 900;
}
.video-slider__content p {
  margin-top: 1.25rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}
.video-slider__content .txt-link {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.video-slider__nav {
  display: none;
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .video-slider__nav,
  .nav-arrows {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .video-slider__nav {
    max-width: 1200px;
  }

  .video-sliders .video-slider__nav {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .video-sliders .video-slider__nav svg:first-child {
    margin-right: 0.625rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="people-love-nextiva">
    <div class="container no-pad">
      <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-start">
        <h2>People love Me.</h2>
        <div class="video-sliders" id="video-sliders">
          <div class="video-slider active">
            <div class="video-slider__video">
              <div class="vid-ct">
                <div class="vid-thumb" id="video-1">
                  <img class="img-fluid vid-thumb-img lazy" src="https://via.placeholder.com/840x473.png?text=Image+One" alt="Alt Text">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="video-slider__content">
              <div class="video-slider__content-inner">
                <h6 class="kicker kicker--light">
                  Customer Story
                </h6>
                <h4>Company Name</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Iste, itaque.</p>
                <span class="txt-link arrow-link">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
                  <img alt="arrow right icon" class="learn-more-arrow" src="https://nextivaweb.imgix.net/icons/Arrow-Right-Hover-Animation.svg" loading="lazy">
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>          
          </div>
          <div class="video-slider">
            <div class="video-slider__video">
              <div class="vid-ct">
                <div class="vid-thumb" id="video-2">
                  <img class="img-fluid vid-thumb-img lazy" src="https://via.placeholder.com/840x473.png?text=Image+Two" alt="Alt Text">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="video-slider__content">
              <div class="video-slider__content-inner">
                <h6 class="kicker kicker--light">
                  Customer Story
                </h6>
                <h4>Another Company</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam est distinctio animi optio eum vero!</p>
                <span class="txt-link arrow-link">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
                  <img alt="arrow right icon" class="learn-more-arrow" src="https://nextivaweb.imgix.net/icons/Arrow-Right-Hover-Animation.svg" loading="lazy">
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>          
          </div>
          <div class="video-slider">
            <div class="video-slider__video">
              <div class="vid-ct">
                <div class="vid-thumb" id="video-3">
                  <img class="img-fluid vid-thumb-img lazy" src="https://via.placeholder.com/840x473.png?text=Image+Three" alt="Alt Text">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="video-slider__content">
              <div class="video-slider__content-inner">
                <h6 class="kicker kicker--light">
                  Customer Story
                </h6>
                <h4>Third Company</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis!</p>
                <span class="txt-link arrow-link">
                  <a href="#">Read more</a>
                  <img alt="arrow right icon" class="learn-more-arrow" src="https://nextivaweb.imgix.net/icons/Arrow-Right-Hover-Animation.svg" loading="lazy">
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>          
          </div>          
          <div class="video-slider__nav">
            <div class="nav-arrows">
              <svg id="left-arrow" class="arrow" fill="none" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <g stroke="#000a70" stroke-width="2.5">
                  <path d="m9 1-7 7 7 7"></path>
                  <path d="m2.5 8h13.5"></path>
                </g>
              </svg>
              <svg id="right-arrow" class="arrow" fill="none" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <g stroke="#000A70" stroke-width="2.5">
                  <path d="m1 8h13.5"></path>
                  <path d="m8 15 7-7-7-7"></path>
                </g>
              </svg>              
            </div>
          </div>                    
        </div>                       
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Instead using `display:none` to hide the non-active elements we can use `position:absolute` and set `opacity:0` to hide the non-active element.
Happy coding.